# Coordinate system in ROS

Tags: ros, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS operates in the ENU Coordinate system(East-North-Up).
In the algorithms for AUV(Autonomous Underwater Vehicles), I need North-East-Down Coordinate system.
What should I do? Change TF or what?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251691/coordinate-system-in-ros/) by [niubc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27846/niubc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always create a new [static transform](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) from ENU to NED and use that coordinate system for your AUV.
You can do that in a terminal by running:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 1.57 0 3.14 world world_ned 30
```

where world and world_ned are the respected ENU and NED frames.

or simply put the following inside a .launch file:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ned_publisher" args="0 0 0 1.57 0 3.14 world world_ned 30"/>
```

and use the world_ned frame for the AUV

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0